# Configure Nginx for routing

Tags: nginx, docker, configuration, reverse-proxy

I am using Nginx docker image on port 80 in my VM (address `x.y.z.w`). So when I try `http://x.y.z.w` in my browser, it is showing me Nginx index file.

Now I am configuring (basically proxy passing) it for my two docker images running on same VM on ports 8081 and 8082. What I want:

```
when I type http://x.y.z.w/a it should go to http://x.y.z.w:8081
when I type http://x.y.z.w/b it should go to http://x.y.z.w:8082
```

For this, I changed a portion in my conf file:

```
     location /a {
        rewrite ^/a(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://x.y.z.w:8081 ;
    }

    location /b {
        rewrite ^/b(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://x.y.z.w:8082 ;
    }
```

It is working as expected. But as all the images are in same machine (have same IP), I want to use `localhost` instead of `x.y.z.w`. But it is not working with `localhost`.

Basically, I don't want to use the hardcoded IP (x.y.z.w) in links, as the IP can change in the future.

Is there any way, Nginx can know the variable IP on which it is running and I may use that IP. Or how can it work with `localhost` with some modification?

Comment: Try docker link https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `localhost` to address another docker container, since it refers to the `loopback` of the container and not of the host. As @Tuan suggested, you can `link` (https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/) containers, so they can communicate via their names. E.g.:

```
docker run --rm -ti --name backend nginx:latest
docker run --rm -ti --name proxy --link backend:backend nginx:latest
```

Now `proxy` knows about `backend`.

Comment: any variable that I can use instead of x.y.z.w ?
does nginx know the address on which it is currently running?

Comment: You can use any hostname for Docker-containers and their links. Nginx has various Variables - also the Hostname of the request (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host).

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced every occurrence of `x.y.z.w` in my `nginx.conf` with `$host` and it is working fine.

For example, instead of `proxy_pass http://x.y.z.w:8081 ;`,

wrote it `proxy_pass http://$host:8081 ;`

Now if my IP (`x.y.z.w`) changes, it does not effect to my applications.